# Alert View Position isn't Center

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I have UIAlertView in UIView. Alert View will appear when error about login occur.

Sometime it worked on Center Position following this picture.

[image]

My code

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:exceptionString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
[alert show];
```

but sometime it worked on Left Position following this picture.

[image]

I want on Center Position only.

How to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: I use same this code...

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:exceptionString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];

Comment: did you set any frame for alertView?

Comment: no, i don't set frame for alert View

Comment: what is your uiview frame

Comment: did you set and frame size for your UIView

Comment: this problem occur on UIView, UITableView, UICollectionView and i don't set frame size for all View.

Comment: if possible link your project @NatthawatSudsang

Comment: @NatthawatSudsang : Post some more code!!

Comment: @NatthawatSudsang did you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you displaying the alert view? Are you setting the frame with this style `initWithFrame`?

It should be something like the following.

```
NSString *exceptionString = "something"; // where ever you get you failed message.

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:exceptionString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
```

Comment: Do you have any other code that might shift the alert view? any transforms on alert? Is this happening on simulator and device or just simulator?

Comment: If it's a broblem then, you should leave it like that. I'm already out.

Comment: I don't shift or tranfrom on alert view. and this problen is occur on device only.

Comment: this problem occur on Simulate too. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

this is may be happen if you are using transform

```
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@NatthawatSudsang` I have seen this before, it happens when you call the UIAlertView multiple times.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" 
                                                message:exceptionString 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
[alert show];

//then some code
//more code

[alert show];
```